# remove href tag a for child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div>
    <a target="_blank" href="/ShowDetails.php">
        <ul>            
            <li>Code1:123456</li>
            <li>Code2:654321</li>
        </ul>
     ...  somethings ....
    </a>
</div>
```

I want when the user clicks on `Code1:123456` that they go to `ShowDetails.php` and when the user clicks on `Code2:654321` nothing happens, so that they can copy the code. Right now when an user clicks `Code2:...` the user goes to `ShowDetails.php` too.
and i want whole div linked to `ShowDetails.php` expect `Code2:654321`

Comment: can you explain last line?

Comment: Move the link inside the first li element?

Comment: in this  only code1 linked to show detail but i want whole div linked to show detail expect Code:2654321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maybe do this:

```
$(function() {
    $("a").on('click', function(e) {

         if (e.target.innerHTML.indexOf('654321')>-1) e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

- Of course give your 'a tag' an ID or class for the selector.
- This solution works if you know the content you're looking for

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x23Lgsdb/1/)

If you have any questions let me know.. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you surround all the list with the `<a>` tag, all the list will be considered as a link. 
You want to move the link to surround only the text in the first item :

```
<div>
    <ul>            
        <li><a target="_blank" href="/ShowDetails.php">Code1:123456</a></li>
        <li>Code2:654321</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

By the way, `target="_blank"` is to be avoided in order to keep accessibility for people who need it. They may be troubled if they can't go on the previous page by clicking the appropriate button.

Comment: in your code only code1 linked to show detail but i want whole div linked to show detail expect Code:2654321

Comment: I don't know if it's possible... Maybe with JS ?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to generate the correct html code in the first place. You can move the link inside the first li-element.

```css
div {
  border: 1px blue dotted;
}

.spacer {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a target="_blank" href="/ShowDetails.php">Code1:123456</a>
    </li>
    <li>Code2:654321</li>
  </ul>
  <a target="_blank" href="/ShowDetails.php">
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Added extra links in places where they are needed.

Comment: i want whole div link to showdetail expect code2:654321.

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying.

Comment: in your code only code1 linked to show detail but i want whole div linked to show detail expect Code:2654321

Comment: Changed my answer to include a second link (seriously though: Don't try to exclude things from being a link while giving a visual clue that they are a link; just create extra links where they are needed. In IE11 you can't even select text in a link without clicking outside the link).